# Deathly Hallows - Did it also refer to Snape, Voldemort, Harry, and Dumbledore?

Tags: harry-potter

**NOTE: This is a theory I just read from Google.  So I will share it to you so I can find some evidence**

The theory quite convinced me.  It says that Dumbledore is death.  Snape, Voldemort,  and Harry are the three brothers.  Snape died from lost love. Voldemort died because of power (his lust for the elder wand). Harry greeted death as an old friend.

When I read this,  the 'brother thing' can prove this as a false theory.  But based on the story of the Peverell Brothers and the description with each character,  it sounds convincing.

But I will make it clear that this is just a theory so my side is still neutral. But is there any evidence to support this?

Comment: It's obviously a fanfic (a nice one). But, what exactly are you asking?

Comment: @ILoveYou I want to look for evidence who can support if this theory can be possible.

Comment: This seems very speculative indeed. I guess you could bring it on-topic by asking "*Did JKR intend for the story of the three brothers to mirror the life and deaths of these three characters*" but even then it's (probably) unanswerable

Comment: Since Rowling actually says it's a beautiful theory and it fits have a +1. Even if it's not canon it's still an interesting read (not that I would have ever imagined it).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### According to J.K. Rowling, this is just a "fan theory", but it does fit with canon

> **Abbie Louise: What's you favourite fan theory?**
>
> **J.K. Rowling:** *Dumbledore as death. It's a beautiful theory and it fits.*
> <sub>[Twitter](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/634666937990152192)</sub>